# is this database designed correctly?

Tags: sql, database-design

I appeared for an interview which went quite well according to me but not according to the interviewer. He asked me several questions which I answered correctly and 2 practicle questions. One of them was related to database.

The question was something like this

A school consist of several classes and each class studies different subjects which are taught by several teachers. You have to design the database so that one can know that which teacher teaches what subject to what class?

It appeared quite simple and I designed it.

something like:

**Teacher table**

```
|  ID    |  Teacher_Name    |
-----------------------------
|   1     |   Ankit         |
|   2     |   Jack          |
```

**Class table**

```
    |  ID    |  class_Name      |
    -----------------------------
    |   1     |   First         |
    |   2     |   Second        |
```

**Subject table**

```
    |  ID    |  subject_Name    |
    -----------------------------
    |   1     |   English       |
    |   2     |   stats         |
```

and a master table to combine them all and to know what teacher teaches what subject to which class

**Master table**

```
    |  ID     | Teacher_id  |  class_id |  subject_id  |
    ----------------------------------------------------
    |   1     |   1         |    1      |      1       |
    |   2     |   1         |    2      |      2       |
```

Just to clear out what I made...I even wrote a select query for the problem even though he didn't asked me to do so.

I am just a beginner at sql so I don't know is this the right way or not but according to me it is quite useful in case I need to make changes to the database. Example addition of a class or a subject.

Now according to him this design will not work at all and He said that I should not even consider my self as a beginner but below the level of beginner.

So please be kind enough to tell me that is this right or not and if its not what is the right way to design the database.

thanks in advance.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this schema. I guess it maybe (1) you have said something else wrong in the interview ; or (2) you have misunderstood his question ; or (3) the interviewer is bad

Comment: i will go with the 3rd option... haha..

actually he pointed out to this specific question. That is the reason i posted it here.

Comment: all the answers seems perfect do I have to select an answer?

Answer (score 6):

> It appeared quite simple

That's probably part of the problem. Most database problems *appear* quite simple. But few of them actually *are* quite simple.

- Not every teacher is qualified to teach every subject in every school. You probably
  need a table that pairs teachers with the subjects they're qualified
  to teach.
- Some entities carry their full identification in their name.
  (Subjects seem to; people don't.) Failing to provide a unique
  constraint on, say, "subject_name" would be a mistake, regardless of
  whether that table has an id number (which might easily be another
  mistake).
- "Master" isn't a term in the problem domain. That is, if you look at
  a college course catalog, you won't find a chapter or section
  entitled "Master chapter", or anything remotely like that. But you
  *will* find a section that tells you which subject is offered during each semester, and
  that's a clue.  In a college, not every course is
  available during every semester.
- You also need a unique constraint on the "master" table {teacher_id,
  class_id, subject_id}.
- In that same table, you need *overlapping* foreign key constraints on
  {teacher_id, subject_id} and {class_id, subject_id}.

I could go on. But here's why *I* wouldn't have hired you.

**You were given ambiguous, incomplete requirements. (That's probably not an accident.) You didn't do enough to clarify them.**

> I am just a beginner at sql

We were all beginners at some point.

Did they want to hire a beginner? If not, that might be another problem.

Comment: Really nice points there @Catcall but wouldn't it be an over attempt and as for the beginner point . I just graduated and need an entry level job. According to work culture here saying intermediate will just kill your chances of getting a job as they think the candidate is being over smart or over confident.. but all in all the points you mentioned were really great.

Comment: Asking a clarifying question is never overkill. Especially in this interview, where clarifying incomplete requirements might have been the whole point of the question. (If you can't do that, your co-workers will spend a lot of costly time fixing your mistakes, or having you do the same work over again.) An alternative point might have been to find out whether you can apply your own knowledge of a course catalog to an incomplete requirement. While it might have been wise not to present yourself to the interviewer as an intermediate SQL user, you told us here you're a beginner. We believe you.

Answer (score 5):

Except for one glitch it seems fine, the glitch it in the Master Table if you assign a teacher to a class with wrong subject, you cannot put a constraint for that in database, IMHO there shoul be one more intermediary table which maps classes and subjects i-e  `ClassSubjectMap`

```
       ----------------------------------------------------
      |  CSMapID |  class_id |  subject_id  |
      ----------------------------------------------------
      |   1     |    1      |      1       |
      ----------------------------------------------------
      |   2     |    2      |      2       |
      ----------------------------------------------------
```

Then this map ID is used in Master table to map teachers with subject, this way a teacher cannot be assigned to teach biology to an engineering class. Except for this other tables seem fine.

Comment: that is definitively a thing that didn't even crossed my mind.. Thanks @Furqan.

Comment: And there could be another table with what subjects a teacher can teach. A teacher with a Math degree can (just an example) teach Algebra and Geometry, a teacher with Physics degree can teach Physics and Thermodynamics, etc.

Comment: Then your Master table would have Foreign Key constraints to the above 2 tables (by Furqan and me).

Comment: Another thing. Did you include FK constraints (and other like Unique and Primary Key ones) in your answer? Or at least give a hint that you assume they are obvious for this simple design?

Answer (score 4):

About [**multi-valued-dependency and 4NF**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't want to explicitly store information about what subjects can be taught by a particular teacher. Actually, we have a real application on educational process, where we don't store such information, and we haven't needed it badly enough to implement yet. So i guess you can go without it too, given that you weren't provided with requirements to restrict users on assigning teacher to subjects and classes.

What i think you would want to restrict is to have just one teacher for each subject taught to a particular class. So i would go for something simple, like table named "Courses", with columns {id, teacher_id, subject_id, class_id, semester_num}, and a unique constraint on {subject_id, class_id, semester_num}, keeping teacher as an attribute here.